# inner join not working in dynamics crm query

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working in a project and I find that they do a query like this:

```csh
LinkEntity link = LinkEntity("table1", "account", "table1acountid", "accountid", JoinOperator.Inner)

link.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("accountid", ConditionOperator.Equal, Id);
```

the relation between table1 and account is 1: N ( we have a lookup to account in table1 form)

The result of the query is always null but when I change `Inner` with `Leftouter`, it works.

Is that query correct with inner join? In which case is it supposed to return records of table1?

Comment: Can you provide sample data from both tables and your results? The link criteria doesn't look right. Shouldn't the `Id` in the `AddCondition` be `"table1accountid"`? The `Leftouter` may not be returning what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you add is not necessary, if used to only return accounts associated with table1, that comes implicitly from the `LinkEntity` statement.
I guess you are missing a `new` directive on the first line too.
Suggest you use **FetchXML Builder** for **[XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com)** to componse the query, which can then be converted to QueryExpression code.

I assume this is the query you want (adding a few attributes to return etc)

```
<fetch >
  <entity name='' >
    <filter>
      <condition attribute='accountid' operator='eq' value='Id' />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='table1' from='table1accountid' to='accountid' link-type='inner' />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```